# Issue with database schema for Django multi tenancy of a saas based invoicing app

Tags: django, postgresql, django-models, multi-tenant, saas

I have a doubt on how shall I approach multi tenancy in Django with the following issue. I am making an invoice app, where each user independently adds to the product/customer (etc etc) models and thereafter uses them to create invoices and inventory.

Now, in this context, please note the following use case:

```
USER A
        Product (Unique on: Key)
         Key    Name        Price   Discount    Tax Total
         Pan    Panasonic   xxxxx   xxxxx   xxxxx   xxxxx
         Sam    Samsung     xxxxx   xxxxx   xxxxx   xxxxx
         Tes    Tesla       xxxxx   xxxxx   xxxxx   xxxxx
         App    Apple       xxxxx   xxxxx   xxxxx   xxxxx

        Cusomer (Unique on: Key)
         Key    Name    Address VAT No  Pending Amount
          c1    Cust1   abcd    1234    xxxxx
          c2    Cust2   xyz     0000    xxxxx
          c3    Cust3   pqr     1111    xxxxx

USER B 
        Product (Unique on: Key)
         Key    Name       Price    Discount    Tax Total
         Pan    Panteen    xxxxx    xxxxx   xxxxx   xxxxx
         Sam    Samsung     pppp    xxxxx   ccccc   dddd
         Tes    Tesla      xxxxx    xxxxx   xxxxx   xxxxx
         App    Apple      xxxxx    aaaa    xxxxx   bbbb

        Cusomer (Unique on: Key)
         Key    Name    Address VAT No  Pending Amount
          a1    Cust1   abcd    1234    xxxxx
          a2    Cust2   xyz     0000    xxxxx
          a3    Cust3   pqr     1111    xxxxx
```

Each user independently creates the rows of these tables. For example, each user can us same product key to name different product, they can also have same product with different price/discount, etc. Same with customers.

And the users should not get access to any part of the table, expect for the part they create (so that User A does not, by mistake touch User B’s data).

Now, what should be my db scheme & how should I proceed?

Moreover, I have a product slug and a customer slug field, which slugiefies the unique filed (i.e. key) to get the user to their respective product/customer page (where they can review nd edit the product/customer data).

I'm planning onto use postgresql in deployment stage.

Answer (score 0):

Put a User foreign key on the table where all data only belongs to that User. Then just query and filter by User on that table, have permission look up the User foreign key, and so on.

Comment: Well, I thought about it, but is that not anti-scaleable (suppose there's 10k users, each having 1k products, so a search would go through 10k*1k)? And how would a slug field on poduct work?

Comment: To add to it, I though of using schema, however, if I'm not wrong, Django does not support Schema in itself, right? In that case, how do I incorporate it (I saw the ticket in Django, but its not a very dynamic solution)